# Passing a progress dialog between two activities?

Tags: java, android

I have two activites `A` and `B`.

What I want to do is.. show  a progress dialog in A, then switch activites to `B` then do some computation and once it is done dismiss this progress dialog.

Is it possible to show the dialog in A, pass it using a Bundle (or other means) to B and then dismiss it once the code has finished running?

Comment: Could you perform your computation within Activity `A` then clear the progress dialog before sliding to `B`?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, progress dialog won't let the user to any action, so why won't you do the logic that is in Activity B in a background thread and when all is done move to Activity B?

A bit more explanation:
If you need to do computation, you do it on background (a separate thread), and while the application perform the computation, you show progress bar to the user, so he won't think the application got stuck for no reason. In the meantime, the user cannot interact with your application, he has to wait for it to finish the computation and dismiss the progress dialog. So I don't see why would you need to launch the activity B before completing activity A? If you need some data from this computation to be passed to Activity B, finish the computation and once its done pass the data to Activity B.

Comment: Could you expand a little as to what you mean? I'm slightly confused.